# Golang behaviour on map definition with static content (compile time construction?)

Tags: go, memory-management

Lets take the following Golang expressions :

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
  foo int,
  bar map[string]MyInterface 
}
type MyInterface interface { /* ... */ }
func firstFunc() { /* ...*/ }
func secondFunc() { /* ...*/ }
```

with the following builder function :

```golang
func NewMyStruct() *MyStruct {
  // Building a map made of only static content, known at compile time
  // Assigning it to a local variable
  m := map[string]MyInterface {
    "first": firstFunc,
    "second": secondFunc,
  }
  /* ... */
  return &MyStruct{
    bar: m, // Copying the map into the struct field
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

I came across this code and decided to try optimizing it in terms of memory management and/or execution time.
Coming from the C++ world, I am used to the "static vs dynamic allocation" dilema and the use of `constexpr`. I am trying to achieve the same goal here in Golang: avoid constructing/allocating a data structure too often in the limits of what the language permits.

**Question 1**: In `NewMyStruct()`, is the temporary map *effectively* assigned to `m` constructed/allocated at each call?

**Question 2**: Can the compiler detect that the temporary map is made of static content, and construct it once for all?

My other solution is to go for a globally defined map and refer to it from the `MyStruct` instances using a pointer.

Comment: Q1: yes. Maps are mutable, not static. Q2: no. Theoretically it might in some compilers in some versions of Go, but the current standard go compiler does not.

Comment: To your last sentence - a pointer to a `map` is rarely needed, as a `map` is already a pointer to a data structure under the hood.

Comment: Then ... what can I do to improve this code? If it is a pointer to an underlying structure, how to ensure shallow copy (thinking about the flyweight pattern)?

Comment: This is premature optimisation.

Comment: @Volker Maybe in Go. From a C++ point of view it is just doing things right by leveraging the language's efficiency...

Comment: This is premature optimisation even in C++. This is probably not being the hot path of your application.

Comment: @Volker In C++ I would have the choice of defining and initializing my data structure in different ways that would have a different efficiency/performance. It then comes down to making the right choice. Here I am not asking how to optimize Go code, but what are the different choices offered by the language, and which one would suits me best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Volker suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947433/golang-behaviour-on-map-definition-with-static-content-compile-time-constructio#comment123648467_69947433), this is almost certainly premature optimization.  However, if you've already found that this has some significant time cost in your program and are just looking for options, [this Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/E96TLGlS8sc) shows a way to construct a map at program startup time and share it.  The essence is just:

```
return &MyStruct{bar: sharedMap, /*...*/}
```

The shared map needs to be created by this point.  If a simple static init is not possible, use [an init function](https://play.golang.org/p/epZYJkCeI6-), or add a `sync.Once` to construct the map only once on the first call to your `New` function.

Comment: I know it is premature optimization, actually I did not ask to optimize this code. Instead I wanted to know if the language/compiler offered sweet features I did not know about to write efficient code (looking for best practices). As I said, in C++, I would have easily avoided the construction of the temporary at each call, and I was trying to learn about Go on this topic.